# RSpec: stub inside let

Tags: rspec

Is this possible?

Example:

```
let(:codes) do
  [double.stub(:msg => 'foo'), double.stub(:msg => 'bar')]
end

expect(codes[0].msg).to eq('foo')
expect(codes[1].msg).to eq('bar')
```

But it raises the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `msg' for {:msg=>"foo"}:Hash
```

and

```
let(:mouse) do
  [
     double.stub(:msg).and_return('foo'),
     double.stub(:msg).and_return('bar')
  ]
end
```

returns `[nil,nil]` for `mouse`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, for RSpec 3 at least, the `stub` method itself doesn't return the double being stubbed. In your case, it returns the hash that was passed into it, as demonstrated by the following:

```
describe 'RSpecs double behavior' do
  describe '#stub' do
    it 'returns the hash passed into it' do
      expect(double.stub(msg: foo)).to eq({msg: 'foo'})
    end
  end
end
```

This appears to be contrary to the [RSpec 2.3 documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs), but the [RSpec 3.0 documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/old-syntax/stub) is silent on the matter and based on [this discussion](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/118), I gather the behavior is intentional.

See Myron Marston's answer for an alternative that avoids the use of `stub` and relies solely on `double`.

As an aside, I think it's helpful in these questions to use valid RSpec syntax in your examples. In this case, you left out the required `describe` and `it` methods.

Answer (score 1):

> This appears to be contrary to the RSpec 2.3 documentation

Sorry, the 2.3 docs are wrong there :(.

> RSpec 3.0 documentation is silent on the matter and based on this discussion, I gather the behavior is intentional.

It's intentional because `stub` is designed to support the fluent interface (`with`, `and_return`, `and_raise`, etc), so it needs to return a message expectation.  We'd welcome a PR that improves the documentation if you want to open one :).

Anyhow, you can pass a hash of method names/return values to `double` so there's no need to use `stub` at all:

```
describe 'stack overflow question' do
  let(:codes) do
    [double(msg: 'foo'), double(msg: 'bar')]
  end

  it "let's you call stub within let" do
    expect(codes[0].msg).to eq('foo')
    expect(codes[1].msg).to eq('bar')
  end
end
```

The docs on `double` mention this:

- http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods#double-instance_method
- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/basics/test-doubles#a-hash-can-be-used-to-define-allowed-messages-and-return-values